# What compression library works with GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, compression

With GAE we can't pick just about any java compression library that works with GAE out-of-the-box, even this [Snappy](https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java) (*which I tried because it was said that its a port of Google's compression lib*) library won't work, throwing access `denied ("java.io.FilePermission")` exception. Which is expected since File I/O is not supported.

So I'd like to ask the community for Java compression libraries that are tested to work with GAE without hacking or repackaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking [class whitelist](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist) you could use java.util.zip to read compressed streams

```
new java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream(inputStream)
```

and

```
new java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream(outputStream)
```

to compress content to an output stream.